# tiff2pdf returns Not a TIFF or MDI file

Tags: pdf

I can view the tiff, yet conversion fails:

```
$ tiff2pdf input.tiff -o foo.pdf
```

returns

```
input.tiff: Not a TIFF or MDI file, bad magic number 13392 (0x3450).
tiff2pdf: Can't open input file input.tiff for reading.
```

.

```
$ file input.tiff
```

returns

```
input.tiff: Netpbm image data, size = 5008 x 6981, rawbits, bitmap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file's extension is a lie, and you indeed do not have a TIFF image. You've got a NetPBM image, which can be converted to TIFF using `pamtotiff` or `pnmtotiff` from the NetPBM library (or any of several other image convertors).

Comment: Indeed. Adding the `format=tiff` flag to the `scanimage` command solved it. I'm using `scanimage` to scan a document into a tiff.